# How create a block without controller and call it in cms block

Tags: magento2, cms-block

I want to show category and category images for this i have created a module and block code :

```
namespace Hello\Brand\Block;

class Brandlisting extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $categoryCollectionFactory;
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
         $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory; 
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getDescendants($category, $levels = 2)
    {
        if ((int)$levels < 1) {
            $levels = 1;
        }
        $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create()
              ->addPathsFilter($category->getPath().'/') 
              ->addLevelFilter($category->getLevel() + $levels);
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

What will be next step ?
How to  call this block in a phtml file to write the html code ?

Answer (score 0):

In your module extension make sure the phtml in the right view frontend  directory, and add this piece of line in cms:

```
{{block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Test" name="test" template="Namespace_Module::test.phtml"}}
```

`Namespace` is your extension company name, `Module` is your extension name.

Your block file should be located at:

> app/code/Namespace/Module/Block/Test.php

and your phtml file should be located at:

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

Comment: Do i need to create any xml file ? like default.xml ?

Comment: How to call Brandlisting block code in that phtml file ?

Comment: @Kanika call the block method from template using $block->getMethodName(param1, param2);

Comment: @Kanika you don't need to create xml file, just use $block->someFunction(); in phtml